# Typing filename in standard open file dialog (Windows 7) - file name suggestion

Tags: windows-7

When you use standard windows open file dialog and start typing it puts files whose name starts with what you type to drop down list. But on another pc with same Windows 7 it also puts first of them into input box in which you type - like FF does with URLS, allowing you to immediately press Enter (without pressing 'Down' to select file).

I don't know why this behavior is different, but I want suggested file name shown in input box.

How could it be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete]
"AutoSuggest"="yes"
"Append Completion"="yes
```

I lacked 2nd parameter